# Using Algebraic Fractions To Find Perimeter

Tags: fractions

Make a formula to find the perimeter of the rectangle, the perimeter is 24 units.

The longer side is $\frac{5}{x+1}$ and the shorter side is $\frac{2}{x}$.

I know that the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ but no idea how.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Do you want to find the perimeter or $x$?

Comment: The question in the book said make a formula to find the perimeter of the rectangle so I think it's that.

Comment: That doesn't make sense if they tell you that the perimeter is $20$. I think they mean use the formula for the perimeter to find $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for any rectangle, the perimeter is given by

$$P=2L+2W$$

where $L$ and $W$ are the lengths and widths.  Plugging in the values you get, we get

$$P=2\left(\frac5{x+1}\right)+2\left(\frac2x\right)=\frac{10}{x+1}+\frac4x=\frac{14x+4}{x(x+1)}$$

Since the perimeter is given as $20$, then

$$24=\frac{14x+4}{x(x+1)}$$

$$24x(x+1)=14x+4$$

$$24x^2+24x=14x+4$$

$$24x^2+10x-4=0$$

$$12x^2+5x-2=0$$

$$x=\frac{-5\pm11}{20}=\frac14,-\frac23$$

Since $x$ can't be negative, or else we'd have negative side lengths, the correct answer is given as

$$x=\frac14$$

Comment: forgot to mention that I looked at the answer sheet and saw "1 quarter" was the answer

Comment: @LSmith Are you solving for $x$?

Comment: I think so (been given it for homework and it's a bit vauge)

Comment: My teacher started it off with $\frac{2(x+1) + 5x}{x(x+1)}$

Comment: @LSmith Huh?  I don't quite see how that is right.  Oh wait, I see

Comment: @LSmith The solution is definitely not 1/4

Comment: Hmm, that's what the answer was in the text book. If it helps the questions before it were about adding and subtracting algebraic fractions. Also I think my teacher mentioned it might lead to the quadratic formula.

Comment: @LSmith I recommend you plug 1/4 in at the beginning of the problem set-up to see that it is false.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad it was 24 not 20.

Comment: @LSmith The solution is still not $1/4$.  Perhaps you copied the problem incorrectly.

Comment: That must be it then, I'll ask my teacher about it tomorrow. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: No problem, we all tried :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50416/discussion-between-l-smith-and-simple-art).

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: @LSmith Yeah, my bad with the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

If the perimeter is supposed to be 24 (not 20 as originally stated), then using the setup from @SimpleArt, we get a quadratic equation of $12x^2+5x-2$. The quadratic formula yields $x=-\frac{2}{3}$ or $x=\frac{1}{4}$. Since negative lengths on a rectangle don't make sense, it seems the correct answer is indeed $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Oh, whoopsies...

Comment: Yeah took me a while but just got it. A learning curve for all of us :)